# What is the difference between "mem_available" and "mem_free" in the Cloudwatch Agent?

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

If I add the following metrics snippet to the cloudwatch agent configuration:

```
  "metrics": {
      "metrics_collected": {
          "mem": {
              "measurement": [
                  "mem_active",
                  "mem_available",
                  "mem_total",
                  "mem_free",
                  "mem_used"
              ],
              "metrics_collection_interval": 3
          }
      },
      "append_dimensions": {
          "AutoScalingGroupName": "${aws:AutoScalingGroupName}"
      },
      "aggregation_dimensions": [[], ["AutoScalingGroupName"]]
  },
```

Cloudwatch will publish metrics for mem_free and mem_available, which have similar values but are not the same number.

The [Amazon documentation](https://github.com/awsdocs/amazon-cloudwatch-user-guide/blob/master/doc_source/metrics-collected-by-CloudWatch-agent.md) says:

`mem_free`: The amount of memory that isn't being used.

`mem_available`:    The amount of memory that is available and can be given instantly to processes. Unit: Bytes

Those don't seem super helpful. How should I interpret these? What is actually being measured? What I'd like to get is some indication of whether the host is in jeopardy of running out of RAM.

Answer (score 1):

Per discussion with Amazon customer support, "available" memory is free memory, plus "buffers, cached and slab" memory.

These correspond to the MemFree and MemAvailable entries in /proc/meminfo.